# Отключить кэширование Ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте, форма заказа отправляется на почту через Ajax запрос. Во всех браузерах кроме Safari вопросов с ее отправлением не возникает, а вот Safari отправляет только первый запрос, а при повторном забивает все в кэш без отправки.

```
$('#form-constructor').submit(function() { 
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "data/constructor.php", 
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
                document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) { document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/"); });
                window.onpageshow = function (event) {
if (event.persisted) {
    window.location.reload();
}};
```

Comment: А у Вас JS код обернут в `$(document).ready(..)`? Вероятно нужно в параметрах запроса указать еще `async: false,` помимо отключения кэша.

Comment: `POST` запросы не кэшируются в принципе.

Answer (score -1):

Почему-то я не разу не слышал о «кеше отправки запроса», может дело в синхронности. Для начала просто попробуйте указать асинхронную отправку, укажите в теле запросе async: true;

Comment: с такими значениями форма вообще не отправляется

Comment: Значит попробуйте async: false;